# IIS 7/8: How to validate the "applicationHost.config" file?

Tags: iis, msdeploy

Is there a utility to test the validity / report issues in the applicationHost.config file?

The xml is valid... and it works fine on IIS 7.5, but msdeploy chokes on it when restoring.

Comment: You shouldn't have asked this question as you already posted the other and only that one contains the information about the problem you met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: You do not need to if everything works.

The errors from msdeploy are bogus (bugs, actually).

Use msdeploy one site at a time with this flag:  -enableLink:AppPoolExtension

And the site and app pool, and ssl certs and more is migrated nicely.